# Unable to enter uppercase C in a ruby file in emacs

Tags: ruby, emacs

Im facing a strange problem.In emacs whenever i press Shift+C,in a ruby file, it interprets it as the control key, so im unable to enter uppercase C.Even keeping the capslock on and pressing C has the same effect.If i change the mode to something else for example java-mode, it works.I have the ruby mode and ruby electric mode installed.
Is this a problem with ruby mode or something else ?

Please Help
Thank You

Comment: http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=15250

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Changing `(define-key ruby-mode-map "C-m" 'newline-and-indent)` to `define-key ruby-mode-map "\C-m" 'newline-and-indent)` in my .emacs fixed it ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `(define-key ruby-mode-map "C-m" 'newline-and-indent)` to `define-key ruby-mode-map "\C-m" 'newline-and-indent)` in .emacs fixes the problem.